# Cant get input parameter to controller, Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

im having a problem passing a data to the controller in MVC3

I have a View that looks like this

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("MyController", "Myfunction", new {id =item.data},  
     new AjaxOptions
                    {
                      UpdateTargetId = "myDiv",
                      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                     })

<div id="myDiv"> </div>
```

And a controller that looks like this

```
       public ActionResult Myfunction(string data)
       {
              //some code
              return PartialView(chart);
       }
```

It all kinda works but the data dont get into the controller (its null when i set a breakpoint), when i hover over the link i see the data in the adressfield. do i have to make some adjustment in the routingtable?

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Please pose "some code" so we can see how `data` is turned into `chart`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It all kinda works but the data dont get into the controller (its null
>   when i set a breakpoint)

---

Change this line:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("MyController", "Myfunction", new {id=item.data},
```

to be:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("MyController", "Myfunction", new {data =item.data},
```

The variable names declared in the POST need to match that captured by the server, in other words your `Controller Action method` is expecting a parameter `data` and its getting passed `id`

Comment: Thanks very much CR41G14, very good written :)  Thanks to you also David L ;)